# Non-principal ultrafilter and ultrapower

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Let $\mathbb{N}_0$ be the usual structure of natural numbers (including 0) in the usual signature with $\leq , +, \times, 0$ and 1. Let $U$ be a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$, and let $\textbf{N}$ be the ultrapower $\mathbb{N}_0^{\omega}/U$. We will identify $\mathbb{N}_0$ with its image in $\mathbb{N}_0^{\omega}/U$ under the natural (diagonal) embedding, and refer to the elements of $\mathbb{N}_0$ as standard $natural \ numbers$. The definition of a prime number remains standard: $x$ is prime if $\forall y:x = y \times z \implies (y = 1 \vee z = 1)$. Prove:
    (1) That in $\textbf{N}$ there exists non-standard primes: primes that are greater than any standard prime. 
    (2) That any elements of $\textbf{N}$ is smaller than some (non-standard) prime.

I have been working on this problem for a long time, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You haven't been able to prove that $(2,3,5,7,11,\dots)/U$ is a prime in $\mathbf N$? What tools do you have available? Do you have [Łoś's theorem(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct#.C5.81o.C5.9B.27s_theorem)?

Comment: @bof: I'm not sure how someone would go about this without just proving Łoś's theorem in general!

Comment: @KyleGannon. You would just prove this particular case of the theorem,

Comment: Do you know that for any $L$-structure $\mathfrak{M}$,any set $I$ and any ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $I$, $\mathfrak{M}^I/ \mathcal{U}$ us elementarily equivalent to $\mathfrak{M}$ ?